# beamer, overlay in allt or fancyvrb

Tags: beamer, verbatim, overlays

I'd like to highlight some text inside an alltt or verbatim or Verbatim (or whatever environment/package that would produce what I want) on some slides.
So, I create a newcommand<> that does the job:

```
\newcommand<>{\highlight}[1]{{\alt#2{\colorbox#2{yellow}{#1}}{#1}}}
```

Indeed, if I use this `\highlight<2>{bla bla}` in a mere frame environment, it does work as I expect (though it adds a space before "bla bla" when highlighted... I don't understand why).

But if I use it inside an alltt or a Verbatim environment, it does not work.

I try to propose a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{alltt,fancyvrb}
\newcommand<>{\highlight}[1]{{\alt#2{\colorbox#2{yellow}{#1}}{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
some text

\highlight<2>{some text to highlight on slide 2 only}

some more text
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{alltt}
some \textit{text}
{\highlight<2>{some text to highlight on slide 2 only}}
some \textbf{more} text
\end{alltt}

\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
some \textit{text}
\highlight<2>{some text to highlight on slide 2 only}
some \textbf{more} text
\end{Verbatim}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The first frame does what I want. The second does not, by far!

I'm not sure I use the Verbatim environment correctly. I mention it to show what I tried. If highlighting with alltt was working, I would be happy.

I've seen some questions about `\alert<x>` in fancyvrb, but I'm not sure the answer applies to my situation (or I don't understand the answer).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.     A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Answer (score 2):

While `alltt` doesn't bother changing the category code of `<` and `>`, because it assumes that ligatures with these characters are intended for output, `verbatim` modes do and there is no interface in `fancyvrb` for changing them back. So you have to do it manually:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{alltt,fancyvrb}
\makeatletter % fix the ligature list and hope for the best
\def\verbatim@nolig@list{\do\`\do\,\do\'\do\-}
\makeatother

\newcommand<>{\highlight}[1]{{\alt#2{\colorbox#2{yellow}{#1}}{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{alltt}
some \textit{text}
{\highlight<2>{some text to highlight on slide 2 only}}
some \textbf{more} text
\end{alltt}

\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
some \textit{text}
\highlight<2>{some text to highlight on slide 2 only}
some \textbf{more} text
\end{Verbatim}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Be advised that `<<` and `>>` in `Verbatim` will appear as « and » if you use the T1 output encoding.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Beamer's built-in `semiverbatim` environment serves the same purpose as `alltt` but preserves overlay specifications.